# Preparing Dataset in Python for apriori

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a data set with all items transacted in sorted in sequence but stored in a single column. I need to prepare the data set so as to able to run apriori on it. apriori needs consequent items bought present in adjacent columns. The number of columns I will have to create will also be configurable like for example I might decide to have  max of 3 columns assuming 3 consecutive items are related to the first item. This 3 can be changed. A sample data and required out put below to explain it better.

```
Items
Item_1
Item_2
Item_3
Item_4
...
```

Required out put Data set

```
Items   Items_col1 Items_col2  Items_col3
Item_1  Item_2      NaN          NaN
Item_2  Item_3       NaN          NaN
Item_3  Item_4       NaN          NaN
Item_1  Item_2      Item_3        NaN
Item_2  Item_3      Item_4        NaN
Item_1  Item_2      Item_3      Item_4
```

Is there a easy way to do this, in python, instead of nested loops as number of columns can keep increasing.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: How are having differentiation with respect to transactions in the initial dataset.

Comment: it is like having one item per transactions, and how many transactions are related to each other will be configurable by saying 3 or 4 or whatever that count may be

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Algorithamically, taking a series of lags and concatenating it columnwise solved the problem.